# Capturing blocking session details in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

I am facing issues with one of the databases like frequent blocking alerts from OEM. The blocking is been cleared in seconds but able to capture the complete session details from  history tables.

Is there way to capture the blocking session details realtime in oracle database  by enabling trace or executing the scripts at database?

DB version: 12c

Comment: this might help `select * from DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` ?

Comment: careful with that views @Moudiz, it requires the enterprise edition of oracle with the diagnostic pack license

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I didnt notice that thanks for the valuable info.